# How to override a negation pattern in the root .gitignore file?

Tags: gitignore

I want Git to ignore a file named `.wh..wh.aufs` in the repo's root directory, because it was generated by my local file system (AUFS). But it doesn't help to place the pattern `*.aufs` in my `~/.config/git/ignore` file, because the repo's root directory *also* has a `.gitignore` file with the negation pattern `!.*`.

Apparently the developers I cloned from want to force-track all files beginning with a dot. I still hope to share changes with them, and don't want to disrupt their arrangements. Without modifying their negation pattern, what's the best way to tell git to ignore my `.wh..wh.aufs` file?

I read the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). The precedence policy seems to be working against me, unless there's something reliable I could do on the command line.

Comment: Couldn't you modify the `.gitignore` and never `git add` it?

Comment: @NovaDenizen: The `git add` was already done in the repo I cloned from. Do you mean that I should never `git commit` it? (I'm new to Git, by the way, but familiar with Mercurial.)

Comment: The usual process in `git` is you edit the file, `git add` the file, then `git commit` to lock in the changes.  If you never `add` the file it will never become part of the commit history.

Comment: @NovaDenizen: I see, thanks for explaining. I'll try that for a while and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the third technique here, maybe?

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Adding the rule to `.git/info/exclude` might work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately `.git/info/exclude` fails. It fails like `~/.config/git/ignore`, because the tracked `.gitignore` takes precedence over both.